# Networking disabled 

Tags: 10.10, network-manager

hi
i have internet working but the network manager applet in the Ubuntu 10.10 says that it is disabled and i am not able to enable it
however i have previously forced the ip address which i am still getting in ifconfig

but in wired section of network connections there is no such interface as eth0
where can i see these settings and how can i enable the network manager applet in the title bar
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

he means `sudo /etc/init.d/networking force-reset`

Answer (score 0):

try `/etc/init.d/networking start`

Comment: i tried this but its still disabled